# Return a variable value by combining dynamic and static text

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have a number of check boxes with unique IDs like so

```
<input id="apple" />
<input id="banana" />
<input id="orange" />
```

I also have a number of variables with the word 'Tree' appended to the end of the ID.  I'm able to get the ID when I click the input, but I'd like to return the **value** of the variable rather than the name that I've constructed.

Can someone please point of what's I'm doing wrong in this code?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var appleTree = 1;
    var bananaTree = 4;
    var orangeTree = 2;

    $('input').click(function() {

        var ID = $(this).attr('id');
        var combinedName = (ID + "Tree");

        console.log(combinedName);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the hashmap as John Green says, or go the evil (but faster) route of eval:

```
console.log(eval(combinedName));
```

EDIT: I don't mean literally faster (I have no idea if it is), I just mean less changes.

Comment: In addition to being evil, the performance is generally much slower, actually.  : )

Comment: @John: Because eval will run anything you put into it - there are literally hundreds of questions on SO addressing exactly that question, I'll let you search and find them.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a hashmap:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var trees = {
       appleTree:1, bananaTree:4, orangeTree:2
   };

   $('input').click(function() {

      var ID = $(this).attr('id');
      var combinedName = (ID + "Tree");
      var treeVal = trees[combinedName];
      console.log(treeVal);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

CombinedName is just a string that you log.
I assume that ID would be apple, banana or orange (in this example) and that you want the value from the variable corresponding to ID + "Tree"

I suggest putting your values in a object with the current variable names as keys. After that you can just reference the object with the string you've made and get the value

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var values = {"appleTree": 1, "bananaTree": 4, "orangeTree": 2}; 

    $('input').click(function() {
        var ID = $(this).attr('id');
        var combinedName = (ID + "Tree");
        console.log(values[combinedName]);
    });
});
```